# "Жюльен" — произношение

Tags: орфоэпия

Верно ли я понимаю, что блюдо *жюльен* произносится мягко, как соответствующее имя и слово *жюри* (см. [здесь](https://kakskolko.ru/kak-verno-proiznosyatsya-slova-zhyul-zhyuri-zhyulen/))?

Comment: `В слове жюри произносится мягенький шипящий [ж’].` - что-то терминология не внушает доверия. Надо бы посмотреть в первоисточники, на которые автор ссылается.

Comment: А в русской фонетике есть мягкое ж? Кроме диалектного произношения "дожжи" не могу припомнить чисто русских примеров.

Comment: @Alex_ander: да полно! Ещё, например, *приезжий, зажженный, визжит* и пр.

Comment: Одназначно _твёрдое_ произношение (пусть и со сдвоенным ж). Иное сейчас именуют "старомосковским произношением" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Ну я за старомосковское.

Comment: Тем не менее, это "говор".

Comment: @Alex_ander: а Вы "жюри" и "Цюрих" произносите твёрдо, что ли?

Comment: Да, твёрдо произношу.

Comment: @Alex_ander А "товарищ генерал" как без [ж’] произнести?

Comment: Стык согласных можно здесь трактовать как озвончение начального щ (шь -> жь), но этот случай далёк от слога с _гласным_, о котором возник вопрос.

Comment: @Alex_ander "Товарищ генерал" - это к вашему вопросу `А в русской фонетике есть мягкое ж?` Ответ - есть. А уж кто, как и где его произносит - это вопрос отдельный. Думаю, реальная картина куда сложнее, чем "московское", "питерское" и "(условные) диалекты", но не слишком в этом силён, поэтому "спрыгну с темы".

Answer (score 2):

Автор статьи ссылается на ряд орфоэпических словарей.
Первый в его списке [dazor.narod.ru — Резниченко И.Л. «Орфоэпический словарь. Произношение. Ударение»](http://slovana.ru/slovari/reznichenko/orfoepicheskij-slovar-reznichenko_0282.htm) говорит нам следующее:

[image: Фрагмент из орфоэпического словаря Резниченко]

Второй: [dazor.narod.ru — Борунова С.Н., Воронцова В.Л., Еськова Н.А. «Орфоэпический словарь российского языка: произношение, ударение, грамматические формы» (под ред. Р. И. Аванесова)](https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0148.htm) не содержит ни *жюльена*, ни *жюльверновского*, а для *жюри* даёт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я смотреть не стал (*см. "Дополнено:" ниже, посмотрел все-таки*).
Таким образом, по крайней мере один словарь приводит оба варианта произношения, но произношение с мягким *ж'* - немного "старорежимное".

*Жюльен* с мягким *ж'* на мой слух звучит манерно. По-русски, разумеется - по-французски только так и можно произнести. Правда, *julienne* во французской кухне не имеет ничего общего с "нашим" *жюльеном*, у них так называют различные овощи, нарезанные соломкой (морковь, огурец и т.п.):

[image: Celery julienne]
(Celery julienne)

**Дополнено:**

[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. «Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию» (§239 «Произношение взятых слов»)](https://nashol.com/2017092996698/spravochnik-po-pravopisaniu-proiznosheniu-literaturnomu-redaktirovaniu-rozental-d-e-djandjakova-e-v-kabanova-n-p-1994.html):

[image: Розенталь]

Собственно, вся статья автора представляет собой большую искаженную цитату из §239 "Произношение **заимствованных** слов" (*а вовсе не **взятых**, как у автора*) этого самого справочника.

Заметим, что у Розенталя речь идёт об **имени** Жюльен, а не о блюде.

Comment: Спасибо за Резниченко! Смотрел только у Аванесова. *Можно сделать вывод, что произносят эти слова по-разному.* Вот откуда такой вывод, я совсем не понял.)))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой :) Я эту фразу уберу, чтобы и другие не спотыкались. Она там в общем-то лишняя и должна была быть раскрыта. Но проще убрать.

Comment: Ой, невнимательно посмотрел: не увидел, что у Резниченко рекомендуется твёрдое произношение. Неприятно.(((